# Position an input in front of div with color and keep input white background AND image

Tags: html, css

I have an input that is positioned inside of a div. When I set the div background color it also changes the input background color. The input has a background image, so I can't simply set the background color for the input.

Thus, I need a way to change the background color of the input that is inside of the div while keeping the background image of the div.

CSS:

```
#searchDiv{
    background:#606060;
    position:relative;
}
#topSearch{
    font: 40px Segoe UI Light;
    width:94%;
    height:60px;
    text-indent: 62px;
    background:white;
    background: url('search_icon.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left; 
  background-size: 60px;
  margin: 10px 3% 10px 3%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="searchDiv">
    <input type="search" id="topSearch"></input>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the input's style like this:

```
    #topSearch {
    font: 40px Segoe UI Light;;
    width:94%;
    height:60px;
    text-indent: 62px;
    background-color:white;
    background-image: url('search_icon.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left; 
    background-size: 60px;
    margin: 10px 3% 10px 3%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add an !important to your input background color

```
 #topSearch{
        font: 40px Segoe UI Light;;
        width:94%;
        height:60px;
        text-indent: 62px;
        background:white !important;
        background: url('search_icon.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: left; 
      background-size: 60px;
      margin: 10px 3% 10px 3%;
    }
```

Comment: While it works, the !important is absolutely abused.  You wouldn't suggest if if you had ever had to undo it from a project where it was all over the place.....

Answer (score 0):

try background: #fff url('search_icon.png') no-repeat center left;
or if you declare multiple backgrounds as shown in your code, comma separate them

Answer (score 0):

In your css for #TopSearch you have the 'background' attribute twice. It will always read the last one. So even thought you are setting it to white you are overwriting it with the very next line for the image.

Change

```
background: white;
```

to

```
background-color: white;
```

And change

```
background: url('search_icon.png');
```

to

```
background-image: url('search_icon.png');
```